# Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: socket, oracle-11g, weblogic, jsp

I running JSP on Oracle 11g, Weblogic 10.3.4. I have 2 managed server and a oracle admin server installed.

I am encountering an error where intermittently the log file of the 2 managed server and admin server will show **java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error**. The application can run for 2 days without showing this error or it can show up a few times in a day. The server load are similar everday.

When this error is been encountered, the server will just stop accepting connections and will not be able to access the application. Even if I try to access the application through localhost, I will not be able to access the JSP pages and a 503 http status is shown but then I am able to access the static HTML page.  I will not be able to access the Oracle 11g Weblogic admin console page. When I take a look at admin server log, it shows that the managed servers are disconnected from the admin server and vice versa.

Magically the application is able to recover by its own and the application is able to access again or I need to restart the server as restarting the service of the application does not work.

The FTP connections that the application is connected to are closed as well.

I am able to ping to telnet to the server port. The event log doesn't seem to be leaving any information. We did run wireshark to see the packet traffic and it seems that the application port is sending a RST, ACK packet to the load balancer.

Any kind help will greatly be appreciated. Should you need more info, feel free to ask me.

### Exception Trace

A-000000> <[Error] GetPageContentTag: pageContext flush error, exception in doEndTag {java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error}>

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error/7747693#7747693).

Basically it indicates a network problem.

Answer (score -1):

There's something on the server-side that is creating bad socket communication and it might be manifesting itself intermittently because it should be invoked from time-to-time, but let's not assume anything and troubleshoot it instead.

Remove all the custom code from Weblogic, see if the problem is still there, if it's not, then you don't need any Weblogic Service Packs. Your next step is to gather all the custom code, put into your Eclipse IDE, put some breakpoints in suspicious places (search for any snippets of code that are creating Sockets or invoking APIs that might doing that) and configure your Managed Server's JVM arguments (Environment > Server > YourManagedServer > 'Remote Start' tab) with this:
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport= dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n

Now, start your Weblogic AdminServer and wait until the problem manifest itself, it should open the DEBUG interface within Eclipse. Happy Debugging :)

More details here:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html

*Obviously, you are not doing that in your PROD environment (only if you can play with it through the weekend of after business hours), so be careful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help. We are not able to produce the above mentioned issue in ou dev or test environment

Comment: Hi, below is the stacktrace i getting.

Comment: Can you remove any sensitive information from your code and paste the contents of the JSP within one these source-code sharing websites? e.g., http://snipplr.com/. also, it would be interesting to see the full stack trace.